# How to get the token id for FCM for the device which uninstall the application?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working on a FCM implementation and have noticed that a device token assigned to a an app installation, can live on even if the app is uninstalled.

Is there any way to know that token is technically no longer valid? So that I can delete the token from the AppServer.

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328654/do-old-gcm-tokens-live-on-even-after-an-uninstall/31828374#31828374)...

Answer (score 0):

Handling what happens when the client app is uninstalled is entirely up to you.

The way I see it, you should simply [detect when your app is being uninstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692571/4625829), if it is, just send a request to your App Server to delete the registration token that is associated with the device (calling `getToken()` to make sure that the registration token you intend to delete is correct).

If ever a scenario comes in where you failed to delete registration tokens and your server somehow manages to send a message to it, I guess that's where [Canonical IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688081/4625829) come into play.

You can also just [check if a registration token from your Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560628/4625829).